# Spring Boot app: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I tried to connect springboot;
When I run, I get an error "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured."

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    dbcp2:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
      username: root
      password: ********(pass)
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
```

mysql config
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjdYl.png)

Output

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Iam unable to run it

Comment: In my case connection string was not in correct form and after fixing it, that works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe dbcp2 stands in your way. Remove it from YAML

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
    username: root
    password: ********(pass)
```

or follow this:
https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-common-dbcp2-connection-pool/

Comment: If I remove Iam getting ClassNotFoundException I think that is mandatory

Comment: there is another issue- driver should start with capital letter:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

And it all should work. I just catched it, and I wonder why InteliJ wouldn't. If you don't receive any hints for YAML file try to 'Download Sources and documentation' from Maven tab on the right. Its an arrow pointing down  icon on top in there